# I install crystal repots 64-bit for visual studio 2022 but it shows me an error

Tags: .net-core, c#-4.0

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304'. The system cannot find the file specified.'

Please any one can help me .....

Comment: Please any one help me solve the problem

Comment: Any one used crystal reports on .net core